# 'process.bat' is not recognized as an internal command

Tags: data-loader

I'm following the following tutorial to try to use the inline dataloader, and now in the last step I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Users\ThaisCarolyne>process.bat "C:\Users\ThaisCarolyne\dataloader\v54.0.0\samples\conf" comissaoUpsertProcess
'process.bat' is not recognized as an internal command
or external, an operable program or a batch file.
```

what could i be doing wrong? I will be grateful to anyone who can help
tutorials I'm following:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/command_line_import_data.htm

https://www.mirketa.com/scheduling-of-data-loader-through-command-line/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because the file is not in your PATH (an "environment variable" that tells DOS/Windows where executables are located), and you are not in the correct directory. You can fix this by switching to the "bin" directory where the process.bat file resides, specifying the full path to the process.bat file, or adding it to your PATH variable.

## Switch Working Directory

In the second link you posted, they show how to switch to the correct directory:

```
Cd C:\Program Files(x86)\salesforce.com\Apex Data Loader 22.0\bin
```

Make sure you're using the correct path name (e.g. it may be `Apex Data Loader 53.0`).

## Specify Full Path

```
C:\Users\ThaisCarolyne>"C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce\Apex Data Loader 53.0\bin\process.bat" "C:\Users\ThaisCarolyne\dataloader\v54.0.0\samples\conf" comissaoUpsertProcess
```

## Update Path

This varies between various versions of Windows, but any modern system should be able to get you to the correct screen by clicking on the start menu or pressing the Windows key (typically four squares, found between Ctrl/Fn and Alt), then typing "path" (without quotes) into the search box, and clicking on either "Edit the system environment variables" or "Edit environment variables for your account".

Once there, you can double-click on the Path variable, which should give you a semicolon separated list of values to edit (just add your path to the end), or an editor that allows you to add a new entry. Either way, once your PATH is set up correctly, you'll should be able to use process.bat from cmd (Command Terminal), ps (PowerShell), or even third-party shells like Bash.

## Alternatives

Of course, you can just create a new batch file yourself. Just create a new text file, put in a series of commands, such as demonstrated in the second link you posted, and save it with ".bat" at the end. Of course, this file will also need to be either in your working directory or on the PATH, but you can place such files on your desktop, for example, or your HOMEPATH (e.g. `C:\Users\ThaisCarolyne`) for easy access.

Comment: thank you very much for the help, now it ran but gave error /0/
if you can take a look i would appreciate it : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/368860/105643?stw=2

Comment: @DersonBarboza Hmm. Check your login history (Setup > Users > Login History, or something like that). I'm not sure what else to say at the moment.