# Error using inline dataloader: WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported

Tags: data-loader, xml

I'm trying to use the line loader and I'm getting this error data:
[image]
I really have no idea why I'm getting this, I'll be adding my mapping:
[image]

I will also leave the csv for the upsert:
[image]

And the process-conf:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="comissaoUpsertProcess"
          class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner"
          scope="prototype">
        <description>Comissao Upsert job gets the Customer record updates from a CSV file and uploads them to salesforce using 'upsert'.</description>
        <property name="name" value="comissaoUpsertProcess"/>
        <property name="configOverrideMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="sfdc.endpoint" value="https://test.salesforce.com/"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.username" value="acesso@ohanaconsultoria.com.br.ohana"/>
                <!-- password below has been encrypted using key file, therefore it will not work without the key setting: process.encryptionKeyFile
                the password is not a valid encrypted value, please generate the real value using encrypt.bat utility -->
                <entry key="sfdc.password" value="a6f43eab15f465ac0582a73850f0fef9223fa4cfdd23249f36ea8b82"/>
                <entry key="process.encryptionKeyFile" value="C:\Users\ThaisCarolyne\.dataloader\dataLoader.key"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.timeoutSecs" value="600"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="200"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.externalIdField" value="Chave__c"/>
                <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Comissao__c"/>
                <entry key="process.operation" value="upsert"/>
                <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="C:\Users\ThaisCarolyne\dataloader\v54.0.0\samples\conf\comissaoUpSertMap.sdl"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="c:\Users\ThaisCarolyne\dataloader\v54.0.0\samples\data\RegistrosparaUpsert.csv"/>
                <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvRead"/>
                <entry key="process.outputSuccess" value="C:\Users\ThaisCarolyne\dataloader\v54.0.0\samples\status\Success.csv"/>
                <entry key="process.outputError" value="C:\Users\ThaisCarolyne\dataloader\v54.0.0\samples\status\Error.csv"/>
                <entry key="process.initialLastRunDate" value="2006-12-01T00:00:00.000-0800"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Who can help I appreciate it, I'm really confused and out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A detail that I almost don't see people talking about is that when entering the password, you must enter "password+security token " that token that you get inside salesforce
[image]